# Is there a way to set the default behavior of GitLab to generate a certain type of license and wiki template?

Tags: git, gitlab

Our team has set up an instance of GitLab that we hope to share with other teams on our campus. Each team will be a different group in our GitLab instance, and we hope to encourage use of MIT licensing and a certain structuring of the repo. wiki pages.

Is there a way to set a default licensing and populate a wiki with a template in GitLab? If not, other recommendations for a strategy are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

License (or other files) template is requested in [issues 599](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/issues/599) (for GitLab Enterprise, but it could be implemented for CE too)
[Merge request 3029](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/c) was *not* merged.

You can already [get all license templates through the API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/license_templates.html).

I don't see any template for wiki though.